# React Syntax in Tutorial Valid or invalid?

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I am new and trying to get better at React. I had a questions about the syntax when each variable is  declared, for ex, inside the `_initialize` method the variables are declared as follows: `var {users, messages} = this.state`. Why is this right? I thought does it have to do with the initial `State` returning an object? FYI This is not my code but from a tutorial. I was just going through the tutorial but I had never seen a variable be declared like this. Some explanation would be nice.

```
var ChatApp = React.createClass({

getInitialState() {
  return {users: [], messages:[], text: ''};
},

componentDidMount() {
  socket.on('init', this._initialize);
  socket.on('send:message', this._messageRecieve);
  socket.on('user:join', this._userJoined);
  socket.on('user:left', this._userLeft);
  socket.on('change:name', this._userChangedName);
},

_initialize(data) {
  var {users, name} = data;
  this.setState({users, user: name});
},

_messageRecieve(message) {
  var {messages} = this.state;
  messages.push(message);
  this.setState({messages});
},
```

I got the code from this tutoriaL for anyone that wanted to see the complete code:

http://danialk.github.io/blog/2013/06/16/reactjs-and-socket-dot-io-chat-application/

Answer (score 0):

This is new syntax that was introduced to JavaScript in 2015 called destructuring. [These are the docs from MDN on destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Given the following object:

```
var person = {
  name: 'alice',
  age: 20
}
```

This:

```
var { name, age } = person
```

is equivalent to this:

```
var name = person.name
var age = person.age
```

You can play around with it in [Babel's repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=true&spec=false&code=var%20person%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'alice'%2C%0A%20%20age%3A%2020%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20%7B%20name%2C%20age%20%7D%20%3D%20person)

Additionally in the same function you'll see the following:

```
this.setState({ users, user: name })
```

This is called simplified object notation. When the property and the value have the same name, which is very common pattern in JavaScript, the value can be omitted.

The above line is equivalent to:

```
this.setState({ users: users, user: name })
```